# Why when changing the size paramter in the unity script it's acting weird?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

The idea of the script is to create random number of spheres in random positions.
Now i tried to play with the Size parameter and got all the problems with it.
I also want later to make the size paramter to be random too. But first i can't figure out what is going on with the size.

The script in c#:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SphereBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _sphereCount;
    private float _sphereSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SphereCount;

    public float SphereSize;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SphereCount = Mathf.Max(0, SphereCount);
        SphereSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SphereSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SphereCount = 100;
        SphereSize = 20.0f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
    }

    private void UpdateSpheres()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SphereCount == _sphereCount && Mathf.Approximately(SphereSize, _sphereSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere");
        foreach (var t in spheres)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SphereCount; i++)
        {
            var o = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            o.tag = "Sphere";
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SphereSize, SphereSize, SphereSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _sphereCount = SphereCount;
        _sphereSize = SphereSize;
    }
}
```

I added a Tag Terrain and added a Tag Sphere. And added a Layer Terrain.
I see that once i add a new Terrain to the Hierarchy it's automatic create on it Spheres and in size 20.

I didn't yet dragged the script to the Terrain.

Now i dragged the script to the Terrain and i changed the size parameter from 20 to 70. Once i changed it to 70 i saw in the editor before running the game the spheres size changed to 70.

But when i'm running the game the size of the spheres is 20.
And when i stop the game and look in the Inspector of the Terrain i see the parameter size in the script is 70 but now i see the spheres in size 20 and when also running the game they are in size 20 and not 70.

A screenshot of the editor you can see the spheres are in size 20 but on the right bottom corner where the script is the size parameter is set to 70:

First time when i typed 70 the spheres changed to size 70 but when running the game it was 20 size and when stopped the game it's all 20 size except the parameter in the script show 70.

I can't figure out why i can't change the size parameter.
Before that it was all the time size 70 even if i changed the size parameter to 20.

I tried to debug using breakpoints i didn't see anything speical in the script side. If the size is 20 then it's 20 all the way. Strange.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just tried your script and it works fine on my computer without any problem

Comment: @UmairM strange i will restart the unity over again. And will try again.

Comment: Or maybe try to comment code in `Reset()` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @UmairM I closed the unity and started it again the program and now it's working. Strange why it happened but now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Yea sometimes weird things happen. Happy coding